# git push -> code review only current change (remote.origin.push overrides push.default)

Tags: git, config, gerrit

My team is using gerrit code review, essentially this means the default push behaviour bypasses the standard workflow so instead we need to use `git push origin HEAD:refs/for/feature` to correctly push our code to get reviewed.

The default push behaviour looks like this:

```
user$ git push --dry-run
To https://gerrit.company.url/project
   83fa2a5..aca3a22  feature -> feature
```

This would bypass the review process which is undesired.

When I set the push ref-spec ([reference here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec#_pushing_refspecs)) to be `refs/heads/*:refs/for/*` this takes a step in the right direction:

```
user $ git config remote.origin.push refs/heads/*:refs/for/*
user$ git push --dry-run
To https://gerrit.company.url/project
 * [new branch]      master -> refs/for/master
 * [new branch]      old_stuff -> refs/for/old_stuff
 * [new branch]      feature -> refs/for/feature
```

Now it is trying to push `feature` to `refs/for/feature` which is what I want but it's also trying to push all my branches to origin.  Gerrit rejects more than one request so I get an output like this:

```
user$ git push
....
To https://gerrit.company.url/project
 ! [remote rejected] master -> refs/for/master (no new changes)
 ! [remote rejected] old_stuff -> refs/for/old_stuff (duplicate request)
 ! [remote rejected] feature -> refs/for/feature (duplicate request)
```

but I found that if I name the current branch it does what I'm expecting:

```
user $ git push origin feature --dry-run
To https://gerrit.company.url/project
 * [new branch]      feature -> refs/for/feature
```

This is great and I will be able to use this but I'd like to narrow it more. I figured if I set `push.default` to `current` it will mean that `git push` will only push the current branch in this way, but to my disappointment:

```
user$ git config push.default current
user$ git push origin --dry-run
To https://gerrit.company.url/project
 * [new branch]      master -> refs/for/master
 * [new branch]      old_stuff -> refs/for/old_stuff
 * [new branch]      feature -> refs/for/feature
```

This seems to be ignoring the `push.default` setting, From the [git config documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-pushdefault):

> push.default
>
> Defines the action `git push` should take if **no refspec is explicitly given**

So the `remote.origin.push` config gets interpreted as an explicit ref spec? Even when setting the default push behaviour to `nothing` it still tries to push all branches:

```
user$ git config push.default nothing
user$ git push
fatal: You didn't specify any refspecs to push, and push.default is "nothing".
user$ git config remote.origin.push refs/heads/*:refs/for/*
user$ git push origin --dry-run
To https://gerrit.company.url/project
 * [new branch]      master -> refs/for/master
 * [new branch]      old_stuff -> refs/for/old_stuff
 * [new branch]      feature -> refs/for/feature
```

What am I missing here? How do I get `git push` to only push the current branch like `feature -> refs/for/feature`?

Comment: Instead of current try using simple

Solution :
git config --global push.default simple

Comment: @poojapatil when `remote.origin.push` is defined then it doesn't make any difference what `push.default` is set to, I demonstrate that in the last example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe what you want to do can be done with just git currently.

I've been able to narrow it down one level further by defining remote server aliases in my config file like below, one for each branch I might want to push, but this is obviously tedious and obnoxious, and I still have to type something like `git push masterrev`.

```
    [remote "origin"]
        url = ssh://gerritserver/product
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    [remote "masterrev"]
        url = ssh://gerritserver/product
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        push = HEAD:refs/for/master
```

The only equivalent I know to provide your original goal is with 3rd party tools like the [git-review](https://docs.openstack.org/infra/git-review/) tool that the OpenStack developers put together for their own use.  It might be worth it if your team is planning to use gerrit, since it provides other functionality like easy access to cherry-picking or checkout of reviews.

As an aside, I believe the push.default setting of "current" means just to assume that the local branch name(s) should be pushed through the remote.*.push modification even if they aren't already known to exist on the server.  It does not limit which branches are pushed to just the "current" one, but rather to use the "current" name(s).

Comment: I did consider changing the push behaviour to only push the necessary branch but hadn't considered using a separate remote.  That would fix several of the issues I had with that approach... I will see how this works and get back to you.

Comment: Unfortunately the `url` contains each employees id in it (to log into the server) and the branch to push to will change every release since we don't use a `master` branch.  So the config file would be different for each member and the branch to push to would change every release.  Thanks for the info and I will look into git-review.

Comment: Mild warning: the initial setup instructions for git-review imply you have to put it's settings in a .gitreview config file, but you can also put them in your git config, which may be better for your usage, depending on whether you want the config to be part of the repo or not.

Comment: I didn't get the seamless simple solution I was hoping for but I guess that's a pretty good indication it doesn't exist (or at least isn't that simple). Thank you for your answer, it wasn't what I was hoping for but  "can't be done with just git currently" is what I got.

Comment: What I finalized on is to add a remote called 'gerrit' which only defines url and push as `HEAD:refs/for/VERSION` which will work for my team, thanks for suggesting separate remote, `git push gerrit` works great!